# Redis Cache - Get the initial timeout set

Tags: redis, timeout

In Redis Cache, is it possible to retrieve the original TimeOut that was set on a key? I know that there is a way to retrieve the pending TimeToLive of any key but I want the original value that was set while creating the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Redis doesn't store the original TTL for keys. It would be interesting to understand the use case that requires this.

You could, however, use a Sorted Set to keep track of the initial TTLs. The idea is that after each call to `EXPIRE`, call `ZADD` on that set with the member being the key's name. The score should be a decimal, where the part before the decimal point is the expiration timestamp and the fractional part is the TTL (padded with 0s according to your max TTL).

To retrieve the initial TTL, call `ZSCORE` on the set with the key's name and extract the part after the decimal point.

Note that by taking this approach you'll have to do some housekeeping, namely removing expired members from the set. To do that, periodically call `ZREMBYSCORE` from -inf to the current timestamp.

Comment: We want to implement Sliding Expiration which is not natively supported by Redis. This was our use case. Any better solution to implement Sliding Expiration?

Comment: Understood. In that case, since it is implied that different keys may have had different initial TTLs, I can't think of a better solution. I do suggest wrapping up the logic (adding, updating & housekeeping) in Lua though.